# liballjoyn.a no such file or directory

Tags: alljoyn

I've installed alljoyn on my raspberry pi and i'm trying to compile the sample code for its basic services. I used the following makefile that i found online with small changes.

```
# Copyright 2010-2011, Qualcomm Innovation Center, Inc.
# 
#    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#    You may obtain a copy of the License at
# 
#        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# 
#    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#    limitations under the License.

# returns current working directory
TOP := $(dir $(CURDIR)/$(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)),$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))

ALLJOYN_DIST := /home/pi/work/alljoyn/core/build/linux/arm/debug/dist/cpp
# for use by AllJoyn developers. Code built from alljoyn_core
#ALLJOYN_DIST := ../../build/linux/x86/debug/dist
#ALLJOYN_DIST := ../../build/linux/x86/release/dist
#ALLJOYN_DIST := ../../build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist
#ALLJOYN_DIST := ../../build/linux/x86_64/release/dist
# for use by AllJoyn developers. Code built from master
#ALLJOYN_DIST := ../../../build/linux/x86/debug/dist
#ALLJOYN_DIST := ../../../build/linux/x86/release/dist
#ALLJOYN_DIST := ../../../build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist
#ALLJOYN_DIST := ../../../build/linux/x86_64/release/dist

OBJ_DIR := obj

BIN_DIR := bin

ALLJOYN_LIB := /home/pi/work/alljoyn/core/build/linux/arm/debug/dist/cpp/lib/liballjoyn.a

CXXFLAGS = -Wall -pipe -std=c++98 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -Wno-long-long -Wno-deprecated -g -DQCC_OS_LINUX -DQCC_OS_GROUP_POSIX -DQCC_CPU_X86

LIBS = -lstdc++ -lcrypto -lpthread -lrt

.PHONY: default clean

default: all

all: basic_client basic_service nameChange_client signal_service signalConsumer_client

basic_client: basic_client.o $(ALLJOYN_LIB)
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $(OBJ_DIR)/basic_client.o $(TOP)$(ALLJOYN_LIB) $(LIBS)

basic_client.o: basic_client.cc $(ALLJOYN_LIB)
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(ALLJOYN_DIST)/inc -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@ basic_client.cc

basic_service: basic_service.o $(ALLJOYN_LIB)
    $(CXX) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $(OBJ_DIR)/basic_service.o $(TOP)$(ALLJOYN_LIB) $(LIBS)

basic_service.o: basic_service.cc $(ALLJOYN_LIB)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(ALLJOYN_DIST)/inc -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@ basic_service.cc

nameChange_client: nameChange_client.o $(ALLJOYN_LIB)
    $(CXX) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $(OBJ_DIR)/nameChange_client.o $(TOP)$(ALLJOYN_LIB) $(LIBS)

nameChange_client.o: nameChange_client.cc $(ALLJOYN_LIB)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(ALLJOYN_DIST)/inc -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@ nameChange_client.cc

signal_service: signal_service.o $(ALLJOYN_LIB)
    $(CXX) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $(OBJ_DIR)/signal_service.o $(TOP)$(ALLJOYN_LIB) $(LIBS)

signal_service.o: signal_service.cc $(ALLJOYN_LIB)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(ALLJOYN_DIST)/inc -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@ signal_service.cc

signalConsumer_client: signalConsumer_client.o $(ALLJOYN_LIB)
    $(CXX) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $(OBJ_DIR)/signalConsumer_client.o $(TOP)$(ALLJOYN_LIB) $(LIBS)

signalConsumer_client.o: signalConsumer_client.cc $(ALLJOYN_LIB)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(ALLJOYN_DIST)/inc -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@ signalConsumer_client.cc

clean: clean_basic_client clean_basic_service clean_nameChange_client clean_signal_service clean_signalConsumer_client
    rmdir $(OBJ_DIR)
    rmdir $(BIN_DIR)

clean_basic_client:
    rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/basic_client.o $(BIN_DIR)/basic_client

clean_basic_service:
    rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/basic_service.o $(BIN_DIR)/basic_service

clean_nameChange_client:
    rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/nameChange_client.o $(BIN_DIR)/nameChange_client

clean_signal_service:
    rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/signal_service.o $(BIN_DIR)/signal_service

clean_signalConsumer_client:
    rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/signalConsumer_client.o $(BIN_DIR)/signalConsumer_client
```

The problem is that i get the following error:

```
g++: error: /home/pi/work/alljoyn/core/build/linux/arm/debug/dist/cpp/samples/basic/ /home/pi/work/alljoyn/core/build/linux/arm/debug/dist/cpp/lib/liballjoyn.a: No such file or directory"
```

So my compiler can't find liballjoyn.a but i don't understand why. The path to the library is the correct one and i also tried

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'/home/pi/work/alljoyn/core/build/linux/arm/debug/dist/cpp/lib/'
```

Can anyone help me?